# RadioGroup with only one selected Item

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I am trying to make a  `RadioGroup` as in the image. I want that only one `RadioButton` should be checked at a time.

This is what I did to achive this.

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/radio1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/radio2" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/radio3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/radio4" />
    </RadioGroup>
</RadioGroup>
```

Here is the Image

[image: What I want]

But by using this I can select any one from each row, i.e. 2 items can be selected.
Like this:

[image]

Please help me...

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313559/how-to-set-only-one-radiobutton-can-be-selected-at-the-time-in-radiogroup/54467859#54467859

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

**UPDATED**

You can dynamically unselect the `RadioButton` when other `RadioButton` is clicked. To do so, I had to play with adding `View` to `ViewGroup`, which is determined by getting its desired `index` of the `TableRow`.

As shown from the above picture, it should be arranged in grid-like layout with only one radio button selected at any given time. Refer to the codes below:

`.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.test.RadioButtonWithTableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:text="Radio 1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio3"
            android:text="Radio 3" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:text="Radio 2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio4"
            android:text="Radio 4" >
        </RadioButton>
    </TableRow>

</com.example.test.RadioButtonWithTableLayout>
```

`.java`:

```
public class RadioButtonWithTableLayout extends TableLayout implements
        OnClickListener {

    private RadioButton mBtnCurrentRadio;

    public RadioButtonWithTableLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RadioButtonWithTableLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final RadioButton mBtnRadio = (RadioButton) v;

        // select only one radio button at any given time
        if (mBtnCurrentRadio != null) {
            mBtnCurrentRadio.setChecked(false);
        }
        mBtnRadio.setChecked(true);
        mBtnCurrentRadio = mBtnRadio;
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index,
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.addView(child, index, params);
        setChildrenOnClickListener((TableRow) child);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.addView(child, params);
        setChildrenOnClickListener((TableRow) child);
    }

    private void setChildrenOnClickListener(TableRow tr) {
        final int c = tr.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            final View v = tr.getChildAt(i);
            if (v instanceof RadioButton) {
                v.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Source: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But by doing this, all the `RadioButton`s will be `vertically` aligned. So the requirement which I have asked that I want to make a group as in the Image is not fulfilled.

Comment: @AnujMathur_07 Try setting parent layout of `RadioGroup` as `RelativeLayout` and playing with `android=alignParentBottom=true` or `android=alignParentRight=true` etc. for each `RadioButton`s until you get desired layout.

Comment: The `RadioButton`s parent is the `RadioGroup`, so none of those attributes are available.

Comment: @AnujMathur_07 Updated the example in the answer. Please try them, and tell me if you still have problems!

Comment: sorry melvkim. It still shows the `RadioButton`s alligned vertically.

Comment: Now for your updated answer. The view is fine, it is how I wanted, but now I can select all the buttons.

Comment: i think you should programatically uncheck all radio buttons if one will be select: button.setChecked(false) & on refresh buttons.clearCheck();

Comment: @AnujMathur_07 Thanks for your wait. I've updated my answer again with `.java` file. I realized you can dynamically inactivate the checked `RadioButton`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now its working fine, I just want to know that can't this be done in the xml file?

Comment: @AnujMathur_07 I don't think so, and here's the reason. `android.view.ViewGroup`'s subclass (e.g. `RelativeLayout`) inherits XML attributes (e.g. `android:layout_alignParentTop`) only to its direct child[ren], which is `RadioGroup` in our example. And, `RadioGroup` must be a direct parent of `RadioButton` objects to associate them together and to instantiate only one button to be checked at a time. Therefore, using the XML structure you provided (Layout->`RadioGroup`->`RadioButton`), we won't be able to freely position `RadioButton` to produce grid-like layout.

Comment: As a side note, we frequently have to add properties to the `RadioButton` objects anyway (e.g. to generate `Toast` to interact with user as he/she selects the buttons), we are most likely going to write a class to manage this custom activity. It is perfectly appropriate to create a class file as one of the widgets in our project path and customize it as we wish.