# How can I check only one radiobutton in two groups if I have two radiogroups with radiobuttons

Tags: java, android, radio-button, radio-group

I have two horizontal radiogroups with radiobuttons and I want to check only one of the radiobuttons but since they are in different radiogroups it allows the radiobutton from the other group to be checked too!Is there any way that when I check only one radiobutton from both groups?

[image]

Here is the code below:

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rgSatisfied"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rg1"
            android:layout_width="383dp"
            android:layout_height="47dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.515"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="RadioButton" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="RadioButton" />


        </RadioGroup>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rg2"
            android:layout_width="378dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.515"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rg1">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="RadioButton" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/other"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="Other" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rgSomewhat"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rg3"
            android:layout_width="383dp"
            android:layout_height="47dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.515"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sample1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Sample2" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="Sample3" />


        </RadioGroup>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rg4"
            android:layout_width="378dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.515"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rg1">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sample4" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Sample5" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/other2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="Other" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </RadioGroup>


    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rgDissatisfied"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rg5"
            android:layout_width="383dp"
            android:layout_height="47dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.515"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="RadioButton" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="RadioButton" />


        </RadioGroup>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rg6"
            android:layout_width="378dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.515"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rg1">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton16"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton17"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="RadioButton" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/other3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="Other" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313559/how-to-set-only-one-radiobutton-can-be-selected-at-the-time-in-radiogroup

Comment: I need one with two radiogroups

Comment: Please share you code here...

Comment: Just posted the code

Comment: So you want one button to be clicked out of six? Or row wise one?

Comment: yes one out of 6,but since there are two radiogroups if you click on another one then you are able to have two radiobuttons clicked and I do not want to allow that in my app

Comment: Then why have you taken 2 radio groups?

Comment: there was no other way to have two rows with radiobuttons other than linear layout which was even worse than radiogroup cuz it allowed all of them to be clicked

Comment: You can use recyclerview if it is the only thing that you want.

Comment: Or else you can add manual condition in your code to remove selection of other group's radio button if it is checked

Comment: I just need them to be in two rows and only one clickable

Comment: Share you Java/Kotlin code here also, I will help you do this.

Comment: I don't have Java code,that's why I wanted to ask

Comment: I need you activity's code

Comment: RadioGroup rg1 = findViewById(R.id.rg1);
        RadioGroup rg2 = findViewById(R.id.rg2);
        rg1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rg2.clearCheck();
            }
        });  I tried this one but it didn't work

Comment: Add full code for that activity

Comment: It's a big project so I can't add all the code but I am interested in only this part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem by listening to changes to both `RadioGroups`.

When a `RadioButton` in one `RadioGroup` is checked, just un-check all `RadioButtons` in the second `RadioGroup`. This is tricky, as the un-checking triggers the listener again, crashing your app. In order to prevent that, you have to add an additional condition: That the `RadioButton` that triggered the event got checked, not un-checked.

Here's the code:

```kotlin
val groupOne = findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.radio_group_one)
val groupTwo = findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.radio_group_two)

val checkedChangeListener =
    RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
        val checkedButton = group.findViewById<RadioButton>(checkedId)
        if (group == groupOne && checkedButton?.isChecked == true) {
            groupTwo.clearCheck()
        }
        if (group == groupTwo && checkedButton?.isChecked == true) {
            groupOne.clearCheck()
        }
    }

groupOne.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedChangeListener)
groupTwo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedChangeListener)
```

Comment: this one helped a lot even tho it's not exactly working the way I wanted it to